# how to modify values of Mat according to some condition in opencv?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, mat

In Matlab `a(a>50)=0` can replace all elements of `a` that are greater than 50 to 0. I want to do same thing with Mat in [OpenCV](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47953-computer-vision-toolbox-opencv-interface). How to do it?

Comment: a>50 gives you a matrix with 0 elements everywhere where a <= 50 and 255 everywhere where your condition holds. So (0 * (a>50)).copyTo(a, a>50) would do this for example. Or just use `a.setTo(cv::Scalar(0), a>50)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is to truncate the image with cv::threshold.

The following should do what you require:

```
cv::threshold(dst, dst, 50, 0, CV_THRESH_TOZERO_INV);
```

this is the function definition

```
double threshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double thresh, double maxval, int type)
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold

Comment: I think the OP is actually looking for `THRESH_TOZERO_INV`, which sets values greater than the threshold to 0. `THRESH_TRUNC` sets values greater than the threshold to the threshold.

Comment: Sorry, OP is "Original Post" or "Original Poster"... either the question or the person who asked it.

Comment: definition of threshold says not only values greater than threshold will be changed to maxvalue but it will set all values less than threshold to 0. but  I want them values less than threshold as it is.

Answer (score 28):

Naah. to do that, just one line:

```
cv::Mat img = imread('your image path');
img.setTo(0,img>50);
```

as simple as that.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!!

Comment: I generally use ther thresholding method... that's also just one statement but this is wayy more flexible and I love it

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes threshold doesn't work because you can have a diferent kind of Mat. If your Mat type supports double, threshold will crash (at least in my android studio).

You can find compare here: 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

So I use the function compare:

```
Mat mask = new Mat(yourMat.rows(), yourMat.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);
Mat ones = org.opencv.core.Mat.ones(yourMat.rows(), yourMat.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);
Scalar alpha = new Scalar(50, CvType.CV_64FC1);
Core.multiply(ones, alpha, ones);

Core.compare(yourMat, zeros, mask, Core.CMP_LT);
```

Here I am creating a matrix with only 50 in all points. After that i am comparing it with yourMat, using CMP_LT (Less than). So all pixels less than 50 will turn in 255 in your mask and 0 if bigger. It is a  mask. So you can just:

```
yourMat.copyTo(yourMat, mask);
```

Now all the pixels bigger than 50 will be zero and all the other will have their own values.