# OpenCV multiplying matrices (cv::Mat) of different types

Tags: c++, opencv, math, matrix, multiplication

Error:

> what():  OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:691: error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op'

Code:

```
// cx is a cv::Mat containing a 1280x720x1 matrix of floats

// what i want is an output of 0.0 where cx <= 0.5 and (cx-0.5)*2 otherwise

auto c0 = (cx > 0.5).mul((cx - 0.5) * 2);
```

I tried:

```
auto c0 = (cx > 0.5).mul((cx - 0.5) * 2, CV_32F);
```

Which didn't work.

Comment: How do you want to subtract a float value from a matrix?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef That should broadcast across the matrix. I don't think that's the issue, the issue is the mask (cx > 0.5) is an int value and I want to multiple the int 0 or 1 by the float on the right side. It says "the output array type must be explicitly specified" but I'm not sure how to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that the type of `(cx > 0.5)` is `CV_8U` and not `CV_32F`.

Take a look at the following code sample:

```
//Initialize 3x3 matrix for example
cv::Mat cx = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 5.0f);

//The type of "logical matrix" result of (cx > 0.5f) is UINT8 (255 where true).
cv::Mat cx_above05 = (cx > 0.5f);
```

I am using [Image Watch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.ImageWatch2017) and Visual Studio 2017 for convenience.

Here is the result of `cv::Mat cx_above05 = (cx > 0.5f)`:

[image]

As you can see, the type is `UINT8` and the value is `255` where `cx>0.5` and `0` where not.

---

You can use [convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) for converting the type to `CV_32F` and dividing by `255`:

```
cx_above05.convertTo(cx_above05 , CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);  //Convert type to float (1.0f where true).
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, the type is `FLOAT32`, and `255` values goes to `1.0f`

---

Complete code sample:

```
cv::Mat cx = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 5.0f);  //Initialize 3x3 matrix for example      
cv::Mat cx_above05 = (cx > 0.5f); //The type of "logical matrix" result of (cx > 0.5f) is UINT8 (255 where true).
cx_above05.convertTo(cx_above05 , CV_32F, 1.0/255.0); //Convert type to float (1.0f where true).
cv::Mat c0 = cx_above05.mul((cx - 0.5f) * 2.0f);
```

Result:
[image]

---

Instead of multiplying by the mask we can use the trick described in OpenCV `pow` [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf0d056b5bd1dc92500d6f6cf6bac41ef):

```
cv::Mat cx = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 5.0f);  //Initialize 3x3 matrix for example      
cv::Mat mask = (cx <= 0.5f); //The type of "logical matrix" result of (cx <= 0.5f) is UINT8 (255 where true).
cv::Mat c0 = (cx - 0.5f) * 2.0f;
cv::subtract(c0, c0, c0, mask);
```

---

I found a more elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884414/4926757) (using [setTo](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a0440e2a164c0b0d8462fb1e487be9876)):

```
cv::Mat c0 = (cx - 0.5f) * 2.0f;
c0.setTo(0, cx <= 0.5f);
```

---

**One line solution:**

The type of the expression `((cx - 0.5f) * 2.0f)` is `cv::MatExpr`, and we can cast it to `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat c0 = ((cv::Mat)((cx - 0.5f) * 2.0f)).setTo(0, cx <= 0.5f);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering at this point whether iterating over all values in the matrix would be more efficient since if the mask is 0 I can avoid the floating point computation in the first place ... I'm not sure if OpenCV does any vectorization magic though (?)

Comment: A simple loop is probably going to be faster, because the code is simple enough for the complier to vectorize. You can also try using [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library, but I don't know if there is an elegant solution for implementing the condition `(cx > 0.5f)`. OpenCV can be built with Eigen, and there is a change that OpenCV mathematical expression does vectorization magics. But `setTo(0, cx <= 0.5f)` most likely reduces the performance.